# 301 Redirect all ?p=xxx to frontpage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We just got our new site up and running. But now I'm trying to sort out the redirects with .htaccess.

Most of them work, but the once with /?p=xxxx wont redirect to mysite.com/something/ now I don't know what all the ?p=xxxx pages are so I just want them to redirect to the frontpage.

Anyone know how to do that. I have seen a lot of these codes. But non of them work for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If anyone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
##non-www to www##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

##redirect "\?p=xxx" to "/frontpage"##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?p=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /frontpage/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi Starkeen, Thanks for your answer. im not an expert on this subject. Can i just copy this code and place it above my 301 rules?

Comment: Yes, keep it above your other Rules.

Comment: Cool, almost got it working. In now goes to www.mysite.nl/frontpage/. I just want it to go to www.mysite.nl. What part should I remove?

Comment: Alright, got it to work. I removed the `RewriteRule ^ /frontpage/? [L,R]` and set it to `RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]` is that correct. This doesn't interfere with other rules?

Comment: @Steggie Yes, this is correct , just change **R** to **R=301** to make the redirection permament.